# Oracle: How can I introspect a view?

Tags: oracle, view, introspection

How can I introspect a view in Oracle?  For example, if I have

```
create view v as select foo, bar from baz
```

I would like to know that `foo` and `bar` are the first and second columns selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use all_tab_columns also for views. So the first two columns of view `v` will be something like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM all_tab_columns
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'V' AND column_id IN (1, 2);
```

Then you can do ask for specific columns:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) TOTAL
  FROM all_tab_columns
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'V' AND (table_name,column_id) IN (('FOO',1), ('BAR',2));
```

If total is 2 means that `foo` and `bar` are the first and second columns selected. You can make this more readable with a case or decode:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TOTAL = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END RESULT FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) TOTAL
      FROM all_tab_columns
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'V' AND (table_name,column_id) IN (('FOO',1), ('BAR',2)));
```